# Difference between 图画 and 绘画

Tags: usage, difference, word, meaning

The dictionary defines both 图画 and 绘画 as drawing & painting. Can both words be used interchangeably? Is there any difference in the words in terms of usage?

Comment: https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E7%BB%98%E7%94%BB verb&noun
https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E5%9B%BE%E7%94%BB  only, users may conclude both are verbs as well as nouns, synonymous as nouns in meaning "drawing",  图画 2) v. scheme; plot; plan (also as noun) attr. pictorial

Answer (score 1):

- 图画：drawing， CAD drawings/blueprint/construction drawing .etc
- 绘画：painting，Art painting/oil painting/literary sketch/photographic painting .etc
- 画画： “画画是一种在二维的平面上以手工方式临摹自然的艺术”，nowadays,its more for kids.

Answer (score 0):

[图画](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/8964/): /tu2 hua4/ is a noun for 'picture',  'drawing' or 'illustration'

[绘画](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/14648/): /hui4 hua4/  is a verb for 'to draw', 'to paint' or 'to illustrate'

"图画" = [图 (picture) + 画 (drawing)]. It is a compound word **noun**

"绘画" = [绘 (to draw) + 画 (drawing)]. It is a compound word **verb**

Comment: Ohh I see. Let's say I wanna make a sentence about "I painted that painting". Is 那张图画是我绘画的。correct?

Comment: I think 绘画 can also be used as a noun. These two are both rather formal words. In casual conversations you usually just say 那张画是我画的。"绘画" when used as a verb has the implication that the person is rather skilled, so you don't really use it to describe yourself. Some example sentences: 印度绘画非常有名。他在绘画时非常认真。小朋友喜欢看图画书。墙上有许多图画。